# Implicit conversion results in argument type mismatch with Tomcat 7

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat7, el

Works fine with tomcat 6.

View: `<h:inputText>` mapped to double in bean.

I looked and unless i'm blind we rely on the EL provided by Tomcat.

When running on Tomcat 7 instead it throws:

> SEVERE: javax.faces.FacesException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
>   javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   argument type mismatch    at
>   com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:142)
>
> Caused by: javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:853)   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:735)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1242)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1242)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1242)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:281)     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1242)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1242)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1231)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    ... 30 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   dk.bording.inside.util.reflect.Reflection.set(Reflection.java:442)    at
>   dk.bording.inside.adapter.entity.MapAdapter.invoke(MapAdapter.java:87)
>     at
>   dk.bording.inside.adapter.entity.MapAdapter.put(MapAdapter.java:50)
>     at javax.el.MapELResolver.setValue(MapELResolver.java:94)   at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:255)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:281)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:207)    at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:257)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.setValue(WeldValueExpression.java:64)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:818)  ...
>   40 more

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is caused by the input that particular field is receiving. JSF2 will conduct implicit conversion based on the inferred dataType of your input. i.e. if the field receives a `0` as input for your supposedly `double` only field, it will still try to cast it to a `Long`.  As recommended in this [thread on the same issue](https://community.jboss.org/thread/186925#comment68842), you should use a `<f:convertNumber/>` converter or bind your field to a `java.lang.Number`.

Comment: This might have worked so I will mark this as accepted.

My error was actually malfunction in a major in house framework that hooks into JSF. As soon I noticed it was involved I should have closed the question but I forgot.

But your answer seems broad enough to stay imo